# Sheet and alert keeps refreshing my page for WKWebView SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I am currently using WKWebView and I added a sheet and an alert inside my wkwebview. However, every time I close the sheet or close the alarm, My WkWebView keeps navigating(loading) back to the origin domain that I specified (for this case, google.com). I an wondering how I can fix this issue.

WebView

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
}
```

Main View

```
struct MainView: View {
   var webView: WebView = WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))

 var body: some View {
  VStack(){
   AlertView()
   webView
   SheetScreenView(webView: $webView)
  }
 }
```

AlertView()

```
...
  Button(action: {
  }, label: {}..alert(isPresented: $isBookmarked) {
                Alert(title: Text(" \(webView.getURL())"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
            }
...
```

SheetScreenView

```
....
@State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            showingSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
...
```

SheetView

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Press to dismiss") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue can be reproduced even without the sheet and alert by just rotating the device. The problem is that in `updateView` (which is going to get called often), you call `load` on the `URLRequest`. This is going to get compounded by the fact that you're storing a view in a `var` which is going to get recreated on every new render of `MainView`, since `Views` in SwiftUI are transient.

The simplest way to avoid this *if your URL isn't going to change* is to just call `load` in `makeUIView`:

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      WebView(request: URLRequest(url:URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }
}
```

If your URL *may* change, you need a way to compare the previous state with the new one. This seems like the shortest (but certainly not only) way to do this:

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    
    @State private var prevURL : URL?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if (prevURL != url) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            uiView.load(request)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { prevURL = url }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
    }
}
```